# 504 Gateway Timeout only with 1 kind of mapserver request (TileWMS in OpenLayers 3)

Tags: openlayers, wms, mapserver, postgis-raster

I'm very new to GIS. With MapServer, I'm calling four kinds of data, but only with this one am I having some HTTP 504 error message randomly. The other three never have that error, but only with this map:

```
MAP
  NAME XXX
  STATUS ON
  SIZE 600 600
  EXTENT 49782.1874916550004855 5149959.5214843796566129 664282.1874916550004855 7904959.5214843796566129
  UNITS METERS
  SHAPEPATH "rast"
  IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
  TEMPLATEPATTERN "itasca"
  WEB
        METADATA
            "wms_enable_request" "*"
        END
  END
  IMAGETYPE PNG
  CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "/tmp/ms_error.txt"
  DEBUG 5
  PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:3857"
  END
  WEB
        IMAGEPATH "/tmp"
        IMAGEURL "http://XXXXXX/tmp/"
        METADATA
            "wfs_title"            "XXXXXX"
            "wfs_onlineresource"   "http://XXXXXX/cgi-bin/mapserv?"
            "wfs_srs"               "EPSG:32719 EPSG:900913 EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857"
            "ows_schemas_location" "http://ogc.dmsolutions.ca"
        END
  END
  LAYER
        NAME balance_hidrico_1
        TYPE raster
        STATUS ON
        DATA "PG:host=192.168.1.XXX port=5432 dbname='XXXXXX' user='postgres' password='XXX' schema='raster' table='balance_hidrico_1' mode='2'"
        DEBUG 5
        PROJECTION
            "init=epsg:32719"
        END
        PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
        CLASS
            NAME "-15"
            EXPRESSION ([pixel] <= -15)
            COLOR "#b87711"
        END   
    END
    # etc...(more LAYERS)
END # Map File
```

I'm calling via JavaScript with OpenLayers 3 with this:

```
this.state.bal_hidrico = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: "http:/XXXXX/cgi-bin/mapserv?",
                serverType: 'mapserver',
                crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
                params: {
                    'LAYERS': 'balance_hidrico_1',
                    'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                    'map' : '/opt/mapfile/map_balance_hidrico.map',
                    'TILED': true
                }
            })
        });
```

As I said, it's only problem with this map and not always...

Could this be a problem with the raster size on the database?

Comment: UPDATE: Well, I've exported the table of the database according to one of those rasters. It size is 15.3MB, compared to the other ones which sizes are near to 1.2MB - 1.8MB.  I think that's the problem... now how could I handle those table with that size to avoid the 504

Comment: You have two WEB sections, which seems a bit odd.

Comment: But can produce a conflict? How it should be?

Comment: `But can produce a conflict?` to be honest I don't know, but I always just have one web section and one web > metadata section, no matter if I'm providing just a WMS or A WMS, plus WCS, plus WFS.  you can use ows_... for metadata that is common to your wfs plus wms, and wfs_ and wms_ for properties specific to a service type.

Comment: Putting aside getting your service to work in OpenLayers, and concentrating on whether the service is actually correctly configured, when you do a GetCapabilities request for your WMS in a browser, like: `http:/XXXXX/cgi-bin/mapserv?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&` do you get any errors?

Comment: The problem has stopped. MapServer is running on a Virtual Machine with low resources... that Map has large tables on the database, the server admin has provided with more resources to that v. machine and problems has gone. We'll move to a real server soon.